# How can I add extra range to d3.js line graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js, linechart

So right now when I create the x.domain of the line graph. All data points will be graphed which is fine. I want the graph to be the width of the dates that are input in a text box not just the dates that contain values.  Right now the graph is only as big as it needs to be.  How can I use x.domain to set the smallest and greatest values.  Right now I am using this.

```
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d.date; }));
```

I tried to use .range but that didn't work at all. So I am not really sure what to do now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify the way the domain is set, not the range. So instead of

```
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d.date; }));
```

you would do

```
x.domain([minDate, maxDate]);
```